# Air compressor won't restart BTFP01012

Tags: repair, switch, valve, compressor, air-compressor

When my dad's BTFP01012 air compressor reaches 150 PSI, he uses the relief valve, and the unit stops working i.e. turns off and does not restart to replenish the air.

So he replaced the pressure switch. The symptom is now random.  After reaching 150 PSI, he uses the relief valve, and the unit sometimes stops working i.e. turns off; otherwise, the unit continues working as usually, continually gathering air. When the machine stops working, it can't be turn on for awhile. What do you think seems to be the problem?

Nameplate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uga0V.jpg

Comment: Is there a thermal overload protector somewhere on the compressor motor?

Comment: In fact, can you post a photo of the compressor motor's nameplate?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I have added a link to the picture of the nameplate. It is too big to put directly here.

Comment: Is there not a nameplate on the motor itself?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Not that I can see. The typography on the device itself is pretty bad; I did not know what was the model number for the longest time.

Comment: Is there something that looks like a push-button on the device's motor?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel No

Comment: strange.  I take it you can't find any reference to motor protection on the labeling or in the manual, either?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel What do you mean by motor protection? As far as labeling goes, all I see is http://powertool.manualsonline.com/manuals/mfg/stanley_bostitch/btfp01012.html?p=2. Otherwise, I see a bunch of other warnings in the manual itself.

Comment: After looking at the manual, it turns out your unit has self-resetting thermal protection.  Is it getting *hot* when it turns off (i.e. hotter than normal)?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel No, I gave it some time. Even when it is completely cooled down, the symptom of not restarting is still happening, and the motor indicates no overheat by touch. It just sounds like it is attempting to restart, but it won't.